# is there any function to set a value to the complete list in java

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

How do add each property value in my model using List? Here is what i do

here is my object : Student.java

```
public class Student {

private String userName;

private String firstName;

private boolean isActive;

// skip the getter setter
}
```

I do call the DB to get the list of student and I want to set the active flag for all users to be either true or false depending on the conditions

My mock data will look something like

```
Student studentList = new Student();
Student student1 = new Student();
student1.setUserName("skol");
student1.setFirstName("soumya");
studentList.add(student1);
Student student2 = new Student();
student1.setUserName("vrac");
student1.setFirstName("vivek");
studentList.add(student2);
```

So now without iterating I want to set all the isActive flag to true, is it possible in java?

right now I am doing something like

```
 studentList.parallelStream.forEach(stu -> {
 stu.setIsActive(true);
 }
 )
```

Comment: add static to "isActive". this will cause all students to 'share' that single field.

Comment: Calling `forEach` on a stream *is* iterating.  Same effect as a `for` loop.

Comment: How do you think streams work?  THey can't magically change everything in a list without iterating, it just writes the for loop for you.  And no, it can't do it in parallel across multiple cores magically-  unless N is very big you wouldn't want to anyway, you'd lose more time setting up the threads and task switching than you'd gain by parallelizing.  For a simple getter, you'd need N to be hundreds of thousands if not millions to gain anything.

Comment: What’s wrong with `studentList.forEach(stu -> stu.setIsActive(true));` regarding a) expressiveness or b) performance? Do you really experience any problem of either kind? The only thing that makes me wonder, is the “call the DB to get the list of student” thing. Is the active property persistent in the DB? Then, make a DB call to set the flag on all records in the DB. Otherwise, there’s nothing wrong with a clear `forEach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You must iterate, one way or another

> So now without iterating I want to set all the `isActive` flag to true, is it possible in java?

No, not without iterating. You have to visit each object and set its property (or call a method that sets its property).

There are multiple ways to iterate in Java. You found one of them, using streams. A plain `for` is the older conventional approach.

As for your use of a parallelized stream to use multiple cores, that provides a significant benefit only if you have very large amounts of data. I suggest not parallelizing until you have a proven problem, *and* testing has proven a benefit, *and* you know for certain your deployment scenario is likely to have cores often available at runtime.

First we need a `Student` class.

```
package work.basil.example;

public class Student
{
    // ---------|  Member Vars  |-------------------------

    private String name;
    private Boolean active;

    // ---------|  Constructors  |-------------------------

    public Student ( String name , Boolean active )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.active = active;
    }

    // ---------|  Logic  |-------------------------

    public void activate ( )
    {
        this.active = Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    // ---------|  Object  |-------------------------

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Student{ " +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                " | active=" + active +
                " }";
    }
}
```

Instantiate some sample data to work with.

```
List < Student > students = List.of(
        new Student( "Alice" , Boolean.FALSE ) ,
        new Student( "Bob" , Boolean.FALSE ) ,
        new Student( "Carol" , Boolean.TRUE )
);
```

### For-each loop

Loop with a for-each loop. Report on our list of `Student` objects before and after we make the change.

```
System.out.println( "students = " + students );
for ( Student student : students )
{
    student.activate();
}
System.out.println( "students = " + students );
```

> students = [Student{ name='Alice' | active=false }, Student{ name='Bob' | active=false }, Student{ name='Carol' | active=true }]
>
> students = [Student{ name='Alice' | active=true }, Student{ name='Bob' | active=true }, Student{ name='Carol' | active=true }]

### `Stream::forEach` loop

Loop with a stream.

We wrote the `activate` method to always switch the value to `TRUE` without the need for an argument. So our lambda can use a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) created via the double-colon `::` syntax. We could just as well have written a lambda taking a `Boolean` argument.

```
System.out.println( "students = " + students );
students.forEach( Student :: activate );
System.out.println( "students = " + students );
```

Same effect.

> students = [Student{ name='Alice' | active=false }, Student{ name='Bob' | active=false }, Student{ name='Carol' | active=true }]
>
> students = [Student{ name='Alice' | active=true }, Student{ name='Bob' | active=true }, Student{ name='Carol' | active=true }]

Comment: Very well Explained ! @Basil

Answer (score 1):

**CASE #1 (With Iteration)** : You dont need stream to set isActive in this case. looping over the list and setting isActive to true should resolve the problem.

```
 studentList.forEach(stu -> {
   stu.setIsActive(true);
 }
```

ParallelStreams might slower the performance incase student list is not large

**CASE #2 (Without Iteration):** As mentioned in above answer set isActive=true by default

Answer (score 0):

In your model try setting default value to true like below please let me know if it works -

```
private boolean isActive = true;
```